# Missing Image with resourceID: res://sample

Tags: android, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui, nativescript-angular

Everything was fine with images until I performed `tns platform clean android` while trying to fix another issue and now it is not loading any image using res:// which ever image I try to use as source in `<Image></Image>` it gives error that image is missing.

`JS: Missing Image with resourceID: res://sample`

while i have checked that in res folder images are there. Can you please tell me why has this happened?

Comment: add code and logcat to get proper idea about error

Comment: @IshanFernando No other error. App runs and every thing else seems fine. Just doesn&#39;t show image. And in the terminal it shows the above error which I posted.

Comment: Reset the application and rebuild again (remove `platforms` and then rebuild with `tns run android`)

Comment: @NickIliev did that but still same issue.

Comment: @NickIliev Can you please help me solve below issue? How to use exoplayer events? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50995788/how-to-use-events-in-nativescript-exoplayer

Comment: Are you user 'run' or preview as argument?