# How to use events in Nativescript ExoPlayer?

Tags: android, events, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, exoplayer

Link to player: https://github.com/nstudio/nativescript-videoplayer

I am using exoplayer in my nativescript project. I want to call a function when the player is ready to play the video. The documentation of this plugin is little bit unclear but player events are mentioned there:

```
Event                   Description
-------------------------------------------------
errorEvent          This event fires when an error in the source code is thrown.
playbackReadyEvent  This event fires when the video is ready.
playbackStartEvent  This event fires when video starts playback.
```

There are so many other events as well but I want to use `playbackReadyEvent` but nowhere in the documentation is mentioned that how to use it.

Please provide any hint or sample code.

Update:

I am using Angular Nativescript and accessing this player using @Viewchild

Component:

```
import { registerElement } from "nativescript-angular/element-registry";
import { Video } from "nativescript-videoplayer";
registerElement("exoplayer", () => require("nativescript-exoplayer").Video);    
@ViewChild("videoplayer") videoPlayer: Video;
```

Template:

`<exoplayer #videoplayer src="https://{{nsrl}}" playbackReady="playbackReadyEvent" class="video-player" autoplay="true" height="320"></exoplayer>`

Comment: In angular I believe you need to do <exoplayer #videoplayer src="https://{{nsrl}}" [playbackReady]="playbackReadyEvent" class="video-player" autoplay="true" height="320"></exoplayer>  put the event in either () or []

Comment: @Nathanael Didn't work. Please help me figure out this issue :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In NativeScript Angular you use:

`<exoplayer #videoplayer src="https://{{nsrl}}" 
(playbackReady)="playbackReadyEvent()" 
(finished)="finished()" class="video-player" autoplay="true" height="320"></exoplayer>`

Comment: Thank you so so much. If you don't mind I have got another issue about the player. If you don't mind please have a look to that as well:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51007738/embeded-video-glitches-in-android-app

Comment: @Nathanael playbackStart doesn't work though correct? i've been trying to hooking to the playback start event, but to no avail. Only the playbackReady works

Comment: Please post a issue in the https://github.com/nstudio/nativescript-plugins/ repo with which platform and how you are wiring it up.